How can the input value be enclosed in a variable?
I'm trying to create a component that will have an input and a button. In input, the user enters his nickname. This nickname, that is, the input value, must be stored in a variable. This variable is needed for a function that creates a link to which the user will be redirected by the button.
My component (next.js)
'use client'

import { Button } from '@nextui-org/react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

let inputValue: any;
let setInputValue: any;

const InputComponent = () => {
  [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event: any) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
        <input id='areaNick' type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder='Введите никнейм' className='bg-transparent border-b-2 border-blue-300 text-white placeholder:text-blue-300 focus:outline-none' />
        <Button radius="lg" className='bg-white text-blue-500 uppercase font-semibold' type="submit" as={Link} href="https://cubeinside.easydonate.ru/">Купить</Button>
        <p>{inputValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputComponent;

Function
client.getPaymentLink(customer, serverID, products, url, email, coupon).then((link) => console.log('link ', link));

All function variables are constant, except for the "customer" and "email" variables. I get the email from the session, but the "customer" should take the value from input. The problem is that the function that reads the value from the input requires the client component, but the function that generates the link does not work in the client component. How can I transfer a variable from a client component to a server component, or how can I place this function in a client component.
I searched the internet for how to declare a variable globally for the entire project, but it uses functions that the client component requires, and in my case it doesn't work.
I followed your answer and created the following components:
component
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";

import { ServerComponent } from "./server";
import { ClientComponent } from "./client";

export default function PayLinkPass() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <ServerComponent>
        {username}
      </ServerComponent>
      <ClientComponent username={username} setUsername={setUsername} />
    </>
  );
}

client
'use client'

import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react"

interface ClientComponentProps {
  username: string;
  setUsername: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
}

export function ClientComponent({ username, setUsername }: ClientComponentProps) {
  const handleInputChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setUsername(event.currentTarget.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="felx flex-col gap-2">
      <input id='areaNick' type="text" value={username} onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder='Введите никнейм' className='bg-transparent border-b-2 border-blue-300 text-white placeholder:text-blue-300 focus:outline-none' />
      <p>{username}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

server
import { Button } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { EasyDonateApiClient } from '@scondic/easydonate-sdk';
import Link from 'next/link';

export function ServerComponent({children}: { children: string }) {

    const client = new EasyDonateApiClient('key');

  const customer = children || ''
  const serverID = '99288';
  const products = { '784789': 1 };
  const url = 'success url';
  const email = 'email';
  const coupon = 'coupon';
  let data;
  client.getPaymentLink(customer, serverID, products, url, email, coupon).then((link) => data = link);
  
    return <>
        <Button radius="lg" className='bg-white text-blue-500 uppercase font-semibold' type="submit" as={Link} href="my-link">Купить</Button>
    </>
  }

As a result, the function returns the error "TypeError: TypeError: Failed to fetch"
client.getPaymentLink(customer, serverID, products, url, email, coupon).then((link) => data = link);



To share data globaly inside your app you can create a Context Provider and then wrap the content of your app at the root layout inside this context provider.
If you simply need to share data between two components, then wrap them inside a client component and declare the variables that will be used inside of it.
It would be something like this:
main component:
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";

import { ServerComponent } from "../server-component";
import { ClientComponent } from "../client-component";

export default function MainComponent() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <ServerComponent />
      <ClientComponent username={username} setUsername={setUsername} />
    </>
  );
}

server component:
export function ServerComponent() {
  /* Do something */

  return <></>
}

client component:
'use client'

import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react"

interface ClientComponentProps {
  username: string;
  setUsername: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
}

export function ClientComponent({ username, setUsername }: ClientComponentProps) {
  const handleInputChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setUsername(event.currentTarget.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="felx flex-col gap-2">
      <input type="text" value={username} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      <p>{username}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

I made it using Typescript, but you don't need to. I hope this can help you.
You can see some other examples at the Nextjs documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers

I added in my question the results of what I got. Can you see what's wrong there?

@zzhuravleff try passing the username state as a prop just like it is being passed to the ClientComponent.
Also, in order to fully understand what that error message means it would be useful to have access to the full error message, it might be possible to find it on the browser console. If possible, expand the error message and show us what it says

But as the error is a TypeError I will leave here some links that have some of the reasons of why this type of errors occurr:
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/fetch#exceptions
